# Foreach, Object reference not set as an instance of an object c#

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, foreach, instance

I wanted to create all individual food objects, which has be picked up by the player but somehow I keep getting the error; object reference not set as an instance of an object.

```
int indexFood;

public Sprite(Graphics paper)
{
    while (indexFood < 50)
    {
        foodArray[indexFood] = new Food();
        indexFood++;
    }
}

public void DrawFood(Graphics drawArea)
{
    foreach (Food food in foodArray)
    {
        food.DrawFood(drawArea);
        food.XPos = 8;
        food.XPos += 32;
    }
}
```

This is the foodClass method code:

```
public void DrawFood(Graphics drawArea)
{
    drawArea.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), xPosFood, yPosFood, size, size);
}
```

Comment: Well how large is `foodArray`? And what does `indexFood` start off as? And why do you have *so* much whitespace?

Comment: Perhaps if you showed how you are initializing `foodArray`?

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: Where do `xPosFood`, `yPosFood`, and `size` come from in `DrawFood`?

Comment: @JonSkeet, out of curiosty why would you question the amount of whitespace?  I can only really see one line of unnecessary white space between the constructor and the DrawFood method, that may have come about from copying and pasting into SO.

Comment: Jon Skeet, Your tip on the arrayLength did it... It tried to draw food from a null object which made the error occur... How could I have not seen that one.  Thanks, happy this got solved verry quickly !

Comment: @Paulie: I think the question was already edited to remove the extra whitespace.

Comment: @Paulie Waulie - it's been edited since Jon made that comment.

Comment: Ah, I see, that explains it then, D'oh

Comment: what is main working of food??????????????//